# How can I completely delete SkyDrive from Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I installed SkyDrive and causes me trouble with Skype. I wish to completely remove SkyDrive from my machine.

Is there any way to do so? It sounds funny as I can't find it in the packages when I search on Powershell or in Control Panel -> Uninstall Programs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:
When I try to run "gpedit.msc" I get [this error](http://imageshack.com/a/img20/2038/hc6k.png).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: *you can't in a proper way at the moment*.

However, you can get *partially* "rid" of it - note the quotes!

## Disabling SkyDrive entirely via local GPO

*This option requires that step one works; if not, go to the registry editor method.*

1. Launch `gpedit.msc` via <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Navigate to **Computer Configuration** / **Administrative Templates** / **Windows Components** / **SkyDrive**.
3. Open up "**Prevent the usage of SkyDrive for file storage**", as shown underneath.

   [image: SkyDrive setting to disable]
4. Set it to "**Enabled**".

   [image: Select "**Enabled**" in the window for the setting]

## Disabling SkyDrive entirely via registry editor

*This method should work regardless of Windows version.*

1. Launch `regedit` via <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Skydrive`.
3. Set `DisableFileSync` to **`1`**.

   [image: Showing the setting DisableFileSync]
4. Sign out, and then in again for the changes to take effect.

<sup>You can also *only* remove it from the navigation pane in Explorer, but I thought you might want to completely disable it.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I had an error, please check my question again, i have edited it.

Comment: @Stefanos.Ioannou Ah, it appears you do not have gpedit.msc, I must be wrong about it being available without Windows 8.1 Pro; I'll see if I can find the pure registry key for it.

Comment: @Stefanos.Ioannou There, that should work for you.

Comment: It was already set to 1. I did that through some settings within the app.

Comment: @Stefanos.Ioannou Hmm, and you've signed out and in?

Comment: Yes. even rebooted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12197/discussion-between-thor-and-stefanos-ioannou)

Comment: Disabling via GP did not have any affect for me. Disabling via registry caused hangs a few moments after openings Explorer for the first time after and reboot (DCOM timeout with SkyDrive's GUID in Event Log) :(

Comment: I don't have a Skydrive directory under "Windows" ...

Comment: Strange. I don't have that registry key and GPO entry at all in my Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to completely remove or delete the Microsoft SkyDrive/OneDrive executable and dll's from your Win8.x OS. We will start with a bit of background then cut to the chase:

Briefing) The SkyDrive schema is protected by the TrustedInstaller which means until MS says you are allowed, you will not be able to complete the task in Windows. In Win7, we were allowed to change file owners in this situation, then bypass TrustedInstaller, however in Win8.x they made this impossible. This means we must use an alt OS to overrule this "situation".

1. Disable SkyDrive/OneDrive via the "metro" settings interface, gpedit.msi policy, or direct registry.
2. Make a backup and/or system restore point of your Windows install partition.
3. Reboot and log into your chosen Alt OS, pref Ubuntu or LinuxMint (they will automount). This may be native, LiveCD, or LiveUSB. In modern bootup keep hitting F12 to see boot order, pick your weapon.
4. After Linux desktop loads, try to find the Win8 filesystem. If the Windows partition doesnt appear on your desktop, try opening any sorta file manager and looking on sidebar. If nothing is there, try rebooting again into Linux. If its still not there, mount it using traditional methods. All modern linux has NTFS support but sometimes windows locks the partition on first reboot or makes it tedious to mount auto. If nothing else works, reboot and keep hitting f2 or delete to get into your bios. Turn off SecureBoot, make boot legacy compatible, then choose legacy first. Set your boot order to your chosen Alt as first in line. Reboot.

   -----> Remember to reverse any changes in BIOS if your Win8 doesnt wanna boot after all of this.
5. Within the Win8 filesystem, try to find windows/system32/ and backup any files or dll's named SkyDrive into any place in your Linux. Add them to a zip file, and copy them into the windows drive, somewhere nice like your desktop. This is your backup of the skydrive files in case SHTF. You have it Linux side and Win side. Note: if you are running Live Linux, the file will not be saved...backup to alternate location outside of Win drive.
6. Delete the SkyDrive files in windows/system32. Throw your fists in the air, let out a large scream, like you just conquered the summit of a mountain against SkyDrive/OneDrive. Prost!
7. Frequently check system32 after updates to make sure MS doesnt sneak it back in. If they do, boot your Alt and delete them. If SHTF replace with your zippped skydrive backup files, or worst case revert to backups/restore.
8. Go onto MS forums and support portal and unleash your anger that they would force you to run this ridiculous service. Its a security risk to have yet another constant pinging service...let alone one that is rooted deep to see your filesystem.

*Disclaimer*: No guarantees -- It runs ok on my PC without these SkyDrive files...no errors. If you run into stuff, please share here so others may develop a tactic to remove it.

Comment: A safer solution would be to go back to a real OS such as Windows 7 instead of this toy OS filled with smartphone and cloud crap.

Comment: +++1 I Agree 2,000,000%.

Answer (score -1):

Get the trial of Revo Uninstaller and do a "forced uninstall" - it will use the uninstaller first then go back through the registry and folders for leftovers - there will be many.